# Adding reference to shared project in an Xamarin iOS project

Tags: android, ios, reference, xamarin

I'm currently trying out Xamarin (on a MacBook, all needed SDKs are installed) and have created a shared project solution.
Within this solution folder there is the autogenerated shared project (called "Project") folder and two projects which I created: An Android project ("AndroidApp") and an iPhone unified single-view Project (iOSApplication).
Now I have added the references to the shared project in both of the other projects so i can use the code from the shared project in the other ones.

So I add "using Project;" add the top of the android project's MainActivity file and it works. I can use classes of the shared project in my Android project.
Doing the same in the iPhone project does not work, and I don't know why.

I'm almost certain that it is my fault because I misunderstood something but I can not imagine what.

Here is a picture of my current workspace in case my discription is unclear.
http://pl.vc/4ndf3

Thank you in advance.